# Angular - How to determine a new item in FormArray?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a form which allows adding multiple children.

There is one field in the child form that contains sensitive information, it is an input field if the child is newly created but read-only if the child is already saved to DB.

How do I achieve this with ArrayForm?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store any additional data in FormGroup as follow

```
  getChild(isNew: boolean): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [undefined, [Validators.required]],
      address: [undefined, [Validators.required]],
      isNew: [isNew]
    });
  }
```

in child Form you can get it from property

```
  @Input()
  public childForm: FormGroup;

  get isNew() {
    return this.childForm.get('isNew').value;
  }
```